# AWS GLUE - Copy data from SQL Server to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I need to migrate data from SQL Server to S3, I would like to do that with GLUE.

Basically, I have SQL Server in place in my VPC and I would like to copy it to S3. I searched for several tutorials on the web and did not find, I would like to know how do I connect to the data source's SQL Server and run a SQL query with a dynamic condition. Would have any tutorial or command how can I do this with Glue?

Comment: Is your SQL Server residing on-prem or EC2, or an RDS?  For migration, why would you want AWS Glue, any specific reasons?  Are you aware of AWS SCT/DMS, ?

Comment: You can issue dynamic sql via Glue. Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375010/4326922