# Filtering JDBC Ingestion with AWS Glue and PySpark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, ingest

I am using AWS Glue to ingest from a mysql database. I know that I can use custom queries when using pyspark-JDBC to ingest data. Does the same apply for when ingesting based on a crawler?
Right now I am using this:

```
datasource =glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="db_name",table_name="table_name")
```

Is there any way that I can ingest, instead of the whole table, only part of it? Like using a `select * from table where column_x > value`.

Comment: You cannot apply a filter on JDBC table when loading from Glue catalog. but you can use JDBC connection to push down the filter to database engine as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375010/4326922 .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping I could avoid that and just ingest from glue catalog directly! Thanks though!

Comment: you should try job bookmarks then https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html but you cannot use SQL here too.

Comment: Thanks again. The problem is with the initial ingestion due to the large volume of the data (after that, bookmarks will be used). If I use "hashfield": "datetime_field"(I know I still won't be able to specify that only e.g. 2019 data should be ingested), will it help or it only works against physical partitions?

Comment: 3 years later this is still not possible?