# Loading data from Oracle table using spark JDBC is extremely slow

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, spark-jdbc

I am trying to read 500 millions records from a table using spark jdbc and then performance join on that tables .
When i execute a sql from sql developer it takes 25 Minutes .
But when i load this using spark JDBC it takes forever last time it ran for 18 hours and then i cancelled it .
I am using AWS-GLUE for this .

this is how i read using spark jdbc

```
df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url","jdbc:oracle:thin://abcd:1521/abcd.com")
.option("user","USER_PROD")
.option("password","ffg#Prod")
.option("numPartitions", 15)
.option("partitionColumn", "OUTSTANDING_ACTIONS")
.option("lowerBound", 0)
.option("upperBound", 1000)
.option("dbtable","FSP.CUSTOMER_CASE")
.option("driver","oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").load()

customer_casedf=df.createOrReplaceTempView("customer_caseOnpremView")
```

I have used  partitionColumn OUTSTANDING_ACTIONS and here is data distribution
Column 1 is  partitionColumn and second is their occurrence

```
1   8988894
0   4227894
5   2264259
9   2263534
8   2262628
2   2261704
3   2260580
4   2260335
7   2259747
6   2257970
```

This is my Join where customer_caseOnpremView table loading is taking more than 18 hours and othere two tables takes 1 minutes

```
ThirdQueryResuletOnprem=spark.sql("SELECT CP.CLIENT_ID,COUNT(1) NoofCases FROM customer_caseOnpremView CC JOIN groupViewOnpremView FG ON FG.ID = CC.OWNER_ID JOIN   client_platformViewOnpremView CP ON CP.CLIENT_ID = SUBSTR(FG.PATH, 2, INSTR(FG.PATH, '/') + INSTR(SUBSTR(FG.PATH, 1 + INSTR(FG.PATH, '/')), '/') - 2) WHERE FG.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND FG.TYPE = 'CLIENT' GROUP BY CP.CLIENT_ID")
```

Please suggest how to make it fast .
I have no of worker from 10 to 40
I have used Executor type standard to GP2 biggest one but no impact on job

Comment: On which type of machine you are performing your job and how many workers you are using in your job?

Comment: @AchyutVyas i have modified the question with all details

Comment: @AtharvThakur I see that your query has few filters which are actually reducing the amount of data. Have you tried pushing this query down to the engine and retrieve the result back to Glue job which will have lot of improvement over performance? refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375010/4326922

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy sorry i did not get the point . I should be putting some filter in Option block ?

Comment: @AtharvThakur I am asking to pass the whole sql query in one of the option block. for example option("dbtable", query) here the query will be your query that will get executed in oracle. Refer to the answer I shared you can use the same with glueContext.read.format()

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Ok thanks i am doing that but do i have to mention anything to improve the performance ? Like mentioning partition key and all ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy i do not see any performance improvement when i used suggested way

Comment: can you post the statement that you tried? if it's still taking time then it will issue in glue script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223969/discussion-between-prabhakar-reddy-and-atharv-thakur).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your query has lot of filters you don't even need to bring in the whole dataset and then apply filter on it. But you can push this query down to db engine which will in turn filter the data and return back the result for Glue job.

This can be done as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375010/4326922 and below is an example for mysql which can be applied for oracle too with few changes.

```
query= "(select ab.id,ab.name,ab.date1,bb.tStartDate from test.test12 ab join test.test34 bb on ab.id=bb.id where ab.date1>'" + args['start_date'] + "') as testresult"

datasource0 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://host.test.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/test").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", query).option("user", "test").option("password", "Password1234").load()
```